# How do I turn around the ticks on digitized faults?

Tags: qgis, symbology

I have downloaded the USGS geology symbology and can assign a symbol, e.g. thrust fault, to a digitized line, but I have no control on the direction in which the ticks showing. How do I tell QGIS in which direction the fault dips? Do I have to think about this when I start digitizing, e.g. dip always to the east or do I have to add an extra field to the attribute table?

Comment: For those not used to geology and this kind of symbology, as well as for better understanding, it would help to provide a screenshot of how it should look like. As well, provide more information, like e.g.: what filetype has the downloded symbology? Where should it be placed? What kind of information determines the direction in which the ticks should show?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using [gsymblib: Geologic symbols library and development for QGIS](https://github.com/afrigeri/geologic-symbols-qgis).

[Sample]

Assigned one of **Thrust fault** style to a line layer. Small black triangles appear at the right hand side of each line segment.

[image]

This is the original line layer (*"faults"*) with 5 lines.

[image]

[Workflow]

(1) Select lines to be changed, and run **Reverse line direction** tool (`Processing Toolbox > Vector geometry`) on them - please note `Selected features only` option is ticked on.

[image]

[image]

The tool will return a new layer *"Reversed"*.

(2) Go back to the original layer (*"faults"* in this example) and Delete selected features.

(3) Merge the *"faults"* and *"Reversed"* layers by **Merge vector layers** tool (`Processing Toolbox > Vector general`) to produce final output.

[image]

Comment: No need for all this work. In QGIS 3.10 (at least) there's a reverse line tool in the advanced digitizing toolbar. During editing, you can select the desired features and click the button to turn then in the other direction.

Comment: @AlexandreNeto I don't disagree.